# Eigenvalue Sums

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem 1:

Let A and B be any 2 × 2 matrices.

Compute the sum of the the eigenvalues of the matrix:

C = AB − BA

Hint: your answer should not depend on A or B.

Comment: **Hint:** What function do you know of that gives you the sum of the eigenvalues in a matrix?  What properties does this function have?

Answer (score 2):

The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues.

Plus,  $$tr(AB) = tr(BA)$$

and the trace is a linear operator.

Hence the sum of the eigenvalues of $C$ is equal to the trace of $C$ that is

$$tr(C) = tr(AB) - tr(BA) = 0$$